# Elasticsearch - How to match number range in string

Tags: python, elasticsearch, elastic-stack

I'd like to write a query which finds log events that contain a name and a number +/- 5. Since I don't know the exact structur of this log event I cannot extract the number in a seperate int field.

My query currently looks like this.

```
    baseQuery = {
            "query": {
                    "bool": {
                    "must": [
                            {"match": {"sim_session" : "session_id"}},
                            {"match": {"event" : "putFilenameHere"}},
                            {"bool": {
                                    "should": [
                                            {"match_phrase": {"event" : "Name"}},
                                            #Search for the line in the event text
                                            {"match": {"event" : "42"}}
                                    ],
                                    "minimum_should_match" : 2
                            }}
                    ]
                    }
            }
            }
```

So I can find events which contain the "Name" and the number "42" (which is treated as a string) but I'd like to find events that contain "Name" and 37 or 38 or 39 or 40 or 41 or 42 or 43 or 44 or 45 or 46 or 47. 
Is there any more clever way to achieve this then executing the same query 11 times with just a different number?

The script executing this query is written in python.

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can apply pre-preprocessing the range to be query:

1. If your field `event` is text, your query string will be automatically tokenized and queried using each number token:

```
"match": {
  "event": "37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45"
}
```

2. If your field `event` is keyword then use terms query:

```
"terms": {
  "event": ["37", "38", "39", "40", "41", "42", "43", "44", "45"]
}
```

Comment: yes, with small range this should be ok, but beware performance when the range is large